# Having issue with understanding Taylor series.

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I am trying to intuitively understand Taylor series. So I see this post:

[Understanding the Taylor Series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2500435/understanding-the-taylor-series)

Answer of user @BobaFret was interesting to me.So I am trying to understand it. I understand how he got
$y = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x - x_0)$ But I fail to realize how he found the equation of higher degree approximation of the function. For example:

" If you want to approximate the function with a tangent "parabola" add higher-order derivatives and powers:
$$y = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x - x_0) + \dfrac{f''(x_0)}{2!}(x - x_0)^2$$

If you want to approximate the function with a tangent "cubic" then continue the pattern:

$$y = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x - x_0) + \dfrac{f''(x_0)}{2!}(x - x_0)^2 + \dfrac{f'''(x_0)}{3!}(x - x_0)^3$$"

And finally generalization of this pattern which is Taylor series.

Comment: The key for the equations is the mean value theorem which is applied repeatedly.

Comment: @Peter I just read the mean value theorem. this theorem is so simple  in first look that I don't know how to make connection with it.

Comment: As a start, if follows $f(x)=f(x_0)+f'(c)(x-x_0)$ for some $c$ between $x$ and $x_0$. Now apply the theorem for $f'(c)$ to get further.

Comment: The truncated taylor expansion is not exactly $f(x)$ , there is always an error-term involving $f(c)$ , which is known as Lagrange remainder term. But in many cases (not always) , this term tends to $0$, so that the infinite taylor expansion represents $f(x) exactly.

Comment: Only in the case of polynomials, the process terminates with a finite exact taylor expansion.

Comment: @Peter I understood $f(x)=f(x_0)+f'(c)(x-x_0)$. but I don't know how to continue. $f'(c)=\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$

Comment: Has you understood everything? I can send some tutorials by Khan Academy and another good tutor, they explain this concept perfectly.

Comment: By the way, Peter's answers are great but can not help you understand what you're stuck at.