# Finding an upper bound on $\arg(\frac{z(z-1)}{2})$ for $z=x+iy$, with $0<x<1$ and $3<y<\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

> I am thinking to find an upper bound (hopefully using Big-O notation) of the following $$\arg\left(\frac{z(z-1)}{2}\right) $$ where $z=x+iy$ , $0<x<1$ and $3<y<\infty$.

I tried the following: $$\arg\left(\frac{z(z-1)}{2}\right) =\arg\left(\frac{(x+iy)(x-1+iy)}{2}\right) $$
So we obtain  $$\arg\left(\frac{z(z-1)}{2}\right) =\arg\left(\frac{x(x-1)-y^2+i(2x-1)y)}{2}\right) $$
I am struggling to solve this question. Please help.

Comment: Hint: $\arg(x+iy)\sim\arctan(y/x)$ (Complete source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)#Computing_from_the_real_and_imaginary_part )

Comment: @Andreas Thanks. Please write as a detailed answer. I will happily accept it.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks. But the wiki page you gave is for Arg and we have in question$\arg$?

Comment: See section on notation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)#Notation

Comment: @Andreas But I think arg and Arg are different. arg is multivalued while Arg is single valued function.

Comment: Yes, that's what Wikipedia says as well. $\text{Arg}$ is just $\arg$ mod $2\pi$.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks again. But, still I cannot think on how to calculate the asymptotic.

Comment: @Blue Thanks for the edit. Please answer. arg is multivalued function. So how do we deal with it

Comment: Asymptotic with respect to what variable? You get $$\arg\left(\frac{z(z-1)}{2}\right) = \arg\left(z(z-1)\right)=\arg(z)+\arg(z-1) = \arctan\left(\frac yx\right)+\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x-1}\right)+\pi$$

Comment: @Andreas Asymptotic with respect to $y$. How did you get a $+\pi$?

Comment: Because $x-1<0$.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks. And what will be the asymptotic with respect to $y$?

Comment: Ok, I wrote an answer that should be complete.

Answer (score 0):

Using [the Wikipedia article on arg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)#Computing_from_the_real_and_imaginary_part) and the domains of $x\in(0,1)$ and $y\in(3,\infty)$, one obtains $$\arg\left(\frac{z(z-1)}{2}\right) = \arg\left(z(z-1)\right)=\arg(z)+\arg(z-1) = \arctan\left(\frac yx\right)+\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x-1}\right)+\pi$$

Next, we can use the taylor expansion of $\arctan$ at [+infinity](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=taylor+expansion+of+arctan%28x%29+at+infinity) and [-infinity](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=taylor+expansion+of+arctan%28x%29+at+-infinity): $$\arctan(X)=\begin{cases}\frac\pi 2 -\frac 1X + \mathcal O\left(\frac{1}{X^3}\right) & \text{ for } X\rightarrow+\infty \\ -\frac\pi 2 -\frac 1X + \mathcal O\left(\frac{1}{X^3}\right) & \text{ for } X\rightarrow-\infty \end{cases}$$

We obtain $$\arg\left(\frac{z(z-1)}{2}\right) = -\frac xy -\frac{x-1}{y} + \pi + \mathcal O\left(\frac{1}{y^3}\right) = \pi+\frac{1-2x}{y} +\mathcal O\left(\frac{1}{y^3}\right)$$

Comment: So you are proving an aymptotic for $\arctan(X)$. Finally how do you get $\arg(z(z-1)/2)=\pi+(1-2x)/y+\mathcal{O}(1/y^3)$? This holds for $y\to \infty$ or $y\to-\infty$?

Comment: @Santevita This holds for $y\rightarrow\infty$ (because $y>3$). For the first arctan, I use $X=y/x > 0$ and for the second arctan I use $X=y/(x-1)<0$, that is why I need both expansions for $X\rightarrow\pm\infty$.

Comment: I request you to please give me a reference of the two expansions of $\arctan$ in a book.

Comment: @Santevita I do not know of a book that contains these specific equations. But I highly recommend reading a textbook with a chapter on "taylor expansions", then you can make these kind of expansions yourself. Any basic calculus textbook should suffice. Here is a useful post on this website on taylor expansions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2500435/understanding-the-taylor-series Here is a YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3d6DsjIBzJ4